# Passing multiple inputs to keras model from tf.dataset API?

Tags: keras

My Keras model has two inputs and three outputs. And my tfrecords file has a pair of images  and pair of labels . If I used `fit_generator` , it will work fine. In which  I created my own generator that provide the two images to both model inputs, the the three labels to the three model outputs. But I want to use `model.fit`. In which I can pass the dataset instance directly. So any one know how can pass a tuple of (x1, x2(, (y1, y2, y3) to Keras model vi tf.dataset API.

**what I used before:**

```
def _parse_function_all(example_proto):

  features = {'image_raw1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'image_raw2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'label1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'label2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'label3': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),

      }


      features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
      image1 = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw1'], tf.uint8)
      image2 = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw2'], tf.uint8)

      image1.set_shape([  224 * 224 * 3])
      image2.set_shape([  224 * 224 * 3])

      image1= tf.reshape(image1, (  224 , 224 , 3))
      image2 = tf.reshape(image2, (224 , 224 , 3))

      label1 = tf.cast(features['label1'], tf.int32)
      label2 = tf.cast(features['label2'], tf.int32)
      label3 = tf.cast(features['label3'], tf.int32)

      image_pair = tf.stack([image1, image2], 0)

      label_pair = tf.stack([label1, label2, label3], 0)

  return image_pair, label_pair


 def data_gen(  sess=None):

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(val_files, num_parallel_reads=8)  

    dataset = dataset(tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=4 * batch_size))


    dataset = dataset(_parse_function_all, num_parallel_calls=4) 
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    dataset_val = dataset_val.prefetch(tf.contrib.data.AUTOTUNE)

    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()

    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            next_val = sess.run(next_element)
            images = np.array(next_val[0])
            labels = np.array(next_val[1])

            y_true1 = one_hot(labels[:, 0], num_classes=num_classes)
            y_true2 = one_hot(labels[:, 1], num_classes=num_classes)
            y_true_3 = labels[:, 2]


            yield ({'input_1': images[:,0], 'input_2': images[:,1]}, {'out_1': y_true1,'out_2': y_true2, 'concatenate':y_true_3 })
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:

          break

model.fit_generator(generator = data_gen(sess))
```

**what I want to use**

```
def _parse_function_all(example_proto):

  features = {'image_raw1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'image_raw2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'label1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'label2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'label3': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      }

      features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
      image1 = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw1'], tf.uint8)
      image2 = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw2'], tf.uint8)

      image1.set_shape([  224 * 224 * 3])
      image2.set_shape([  224 * 224 * 3])

      image1= tf.reshape(image1, (  224 , 224 , 3))
      image2 = tf.reshape(image2, (224 , 224 , 3))

      label1 = tf.cast(features['label1'], tf.int32)
      label2 = tf.cast(features['label2'], tf.int32)
      label3 = tf.cast(features['label3'], tf.int32)

      image_pair = tf.stack([image1, image2], 0)

      label_pair = tf.stack([label1, label2, label3], 0)

  return ((image1, image2), (label1, label2, label3))  # it gave error in this line. because it is wrong way. 

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(val_files, num_parallel_reads=8)  
    dataset = dataset(tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=4 * batch_size))
    dataset = dataset(_parse_function_all, num_parallel_calls=4) 
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset_val = dataset_val.prefetch(tf.contrib.data.AUTOTUNE)

    model.fit(dataset_val)
```

So Is there any solution for passing tuple of ( image, labels) to Keras model that have multiple inputs?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new version of  TensorFlow (1.14 and above( , tf.keras allow me to pass multiple instances to model.fit.